# Memory leak with void*

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

How can I stop this memory leak.

I have created a vector like this in the header:

```
static std::vector< uint32_t> m_Map;
void* m_mapRegion
```

Then in the .cpp

```
m_Map.resize( 450 );
m_mapRegion = &m_map[0];
```

I then use m_mapRegion to access the vector via the address and all is OK.  When I delete the object then the test tools flag up a memory leak.  How can I get rid of the error?  Thanks.

I tried this:

```
m_Map.clear();
m_mapRegion = NULL;
```

What is the correct way?

The error message given is:

```
HWTests.cpp:188: error: Failure in TEST(HW, Test)
Memory leak(s) found.
Alloc num (653) Leak size: 2400 Allocated at: <unknown> and line: 0. Type: "new"
 Memory: <0x11b2a70> Content: ""
Total number of leaks:  1
```

In the Test all I do is this:

```
HW HWAccessor;  //This line causes the error.
```

Comment: You have declared the vector as static, so that is probably the reason you get false positive from your test tool

Comment: How are you deleting the object?

Comment: What is `HW`? Can you boil down your problem to a self-contained, small, compilable example?

Comment: I do not use new at all, anywhere in my code or tests.  More information in the question.

Comment: I have, take away those lines and the error goes away.  I guess the tool is wrong.

Comment: @Claptrap, I have only one object per test and at the end of the test it is destroyed, by going out of scope.  Should not the static be too as no other objects exist until the next test.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why isn't `m_mapRegion` a `uint32_t *` at least? Or, of course, why don't you just use indexing into the `std::vector`?

Comment: @user1876942 No, the static object will not be destroyed if the instance goes out of scope. If you want that, remove the `static` keyword and make it an instance variable.

Comment: I need it to be static.  Why is that static still there no objects exist?  Is there anyway to delete it at the end of the tests? Thanks.

Comment: @unwind  because I am making HW register tests and the real code uses memory mapping.  I am trying to write code that will test it without HW.

Answer (score 3):

You never actually called `new` to dynamically allocate memory, so calling `delete` is not necessary.

Comment: This is what I'm thinking, so is this really a memory leak?

Comment: No, it's not. But I can easily see all kind of bad things happening if your code actually contains a `delete`. You never showed that part. Maybe you should post all code and the warning.

Comment: The lines you posted do not cause memory leaks. But if a tool told you to double-check, maybe you misinterpreted it's message and there is something in the lines you did not post. We can only check the lines you posted.

Comment: I will post the error message in a second.  If I take away those lines then the error message goes away too.  The error is in those lines somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

`vector::clear` may not necessarily free up the memory in heap. It merely cleans up the vector, so that `size` would report `0`. The vector must be destroyed, or `std::swap` with another temporary `vector`. The temporary should cease to exist soon.

```
{ 
  vector<uint32_t> temp;
  std::swap(temp, m_Map);
}
```